# How to find latitude and longitude in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, latitude-longitude

I am working on web analytics, we are using `node.js` in server side, we are sending the data using http request`(express framework)`.

`Requirement`:Have to find the latitude and longitude of the visitor.

My question is how to find the latitude and longitude in `node.js`? Any framework available?

Comment: Only way I can think of doing something like this would be to run their IP through [geoIP](http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing) or a similar service.

Comment: You could do this client side with google maps api

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I strongly recommend to use the HTML5 geolocation API inside the browser and then send visitor location information to your server – that's way more accurate than using geolocation from IP addresses on the server-side. You will be getting the location of the ISPs, which can be quite far away, and in addition the IP-to-location databases aren't always up to date with the latest changes, so you might won't get any data for a particular IP address.

To find out more about this topic take a look at MaxMind, which offers a popular IP-to-location database published some statistics on its database: [GeoIP City Accuracy for Selected Countries](http://www.maxmind.com/en/city_accuracy)

Here's a great example of using [`navigator.geolocation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation):

- [Real-Time Geolocation Service with Node.js](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/11/real-time-geolocation-service-with-node-js/)

Comment: And then the user will see "XX wants to get your location" and clicks disallow. Brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

If the visitor is visiting your site via a browser, then you are asking the question on the wrong technology. 
Node.js is a serverside technology, which means it can't access the user's geolocation directly.

What you should be asking is how to get geolocation using javascript on the clientside, and then simply send that information to your server via Ajax. 
That question is very easy to answer: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp . There are ofcourse libraries that will ease the use of this.

If you can't, don't want to, or don't want to bother getting the information clientSide, then you can try and match the IP (which is what Maxmind does, though I'm not sure if they'll give you the longitude and latitide or just a city name).
However these will not be exact, especially if your visitors are using devices with geolocation capabilities (such as mobile phones).

Comment: geolocation supports from ie 9+.

Answer (score 0):

1) you can also use this npm package for knowing lat long of your ip

https://www.npmjs.com/package/geoip-lite

```
{ range: [ 3479298048, 3479300095 ],
  country: 'US',
  region: 'TX',
  eu: '0',
  timezone: 'America/Chicago',
  city: 'San Antonio',
  ll: [ 29.4969, -98.4032 ],
  metro: 641,
  area: 1000 }
```

it give you this format of information

---

2) this package give you some useful information as you want

https://www.npmjs.com/package/iplocation

```
iplocation('56.70.97.8', [], (error, res) => {

    /* res:

        {
            as: 'AS11286 KeyBank National Association',
            city: 'Cleveland',
            country: 'United States',
            countryCode: 'US',
            isp: 'KeyBank National Association',
            lat: 41.4875,
            lon: -81.6724,
            org: 'KeyBank National Association',
            query: '156.77.54.32',
            region: 'OH',
            regionName: 'Ohio',
            status: 'success',
            timezone: 'America/New_York',
            zip: '44115'
        }

    */

});
```

and it give you this format of information

Comment: Can't get location based on IP as in case of VPN or any kind of IP masking software being used, this data will be wrong. The accepted answer is the only way for it.